# Sequelize create throws a unique constraint error

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to run a simple `create` call with a many to many association between two models but I run into a unique constraint error when i try to add an existing model as an association.

I have tried calling create without include and then calling the setReward method and this does work. i do know that through inspection of sequelize lib/model.js that my associated model always has the property isNewRecord set to true.

```
const reward = await db.reward.create({
  title: 'reward 1', ...
});

const level = await db.level.create({
  title: 'level 1', rewards: [reward], ...
}, {
  include: [{
    model: db.reward,
    as: 'rewards'
  }]
});
```

Here is a portion of the output. Sequelize is attempting to save my already saved model.

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `reward` (`id`,`fid`,`type`,`title`,`description`,`unlockable`,`unlocked`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('53428154-251c-4f01-92cd-4724f0bd3fe9','test','PROFILE_BADGE','Reward 1','Reward 1',true,false,'2019-09-04 13:24:28','2019-09-0413:24:28');

Executing (default): INSERT INTO `level` (`id`,`fid`,`order`,`title`,`description`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('17ed2675-0754-48df-93a6-53d9d770189d','test',1,'Level 1','Level 1','2019-09-04 13:24:28','2019-09-04 13:24:28');

Executing (default): INSERT INTO `reward` (`id`,`fid`,`type`,`title`,`description`,`unlockable`,`unlocked`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('53428154-251c-4f01-92cd-4724f0bd3fe9','test','PROFILE_BADGE','Reward 1','Reward 1',true,false,'2019-09-04 13:24:28','2019-09-0413:24:28');

{ SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:226:16)
    at Query.handler [as onResult] (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:68:23)
    at Query.execute (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:449:32)
    at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:72:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (C:\Users\jamesg\Documents\dtl-api-profile\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:79:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
...
```

Comment: Must be a bug in sequelize